# Horizontal type accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built 2 tabs which each slide down when the expand button is clicked. However what I would like to happen is that if one is already expanded and the other is clicked if for it to automatically close/hide the other. At the moment I have two functions

```
$(function() {
    $("#content1 h3.expand").toggler();
    $("#content1 div.demo").expandAll({trigger: "h3.expand", ref: "h3.expand"});

    $("#content1 div.post").expandAll({
      expTxt : "click to expand +", 
      cllpsTxt : "collapse -",
      ref : "div.collapse", 
      localLinks: "p.top a"    
    });    
});

$(function() {
    $("#content2 h3.expand").toggler();
    $("#content2 div.demo").expandAll({trigger: "h3.expand", ref: "h3.expand"});

    $("#content2 div.post").expandAll({
      expTxt : "click to expand +", 
      cllpsTxt : "collapse -",
      ref : "div.collapse", 
      localLinks: "p.top a"    
    });    
});
```

Also if you need access to my full code, let me know and I will put it on a bit of webspace.

Thanks